# What range of the electromagnetic spectrum will a .RAW image generally encompass?

Tags: raw

I believe that most cameras contain an infra-red filter, thereby capturing mostly the RGB spectrum only. Perhaps by taking out that filter (or buying a NIR camera) one can see more of the spectrum (instead of only about 390 to 700 nm)?

Comment: Technically it's not filter but blocker.

Comment: @Alex.S  "blocker" is just a filter with high optical density in the wavelength  range of interest.  No reason to quibble on this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much every consumer camera made for general photography has an integrated IR/UV filter, so the camera only captures visible light by design.

Yes, it's frequently possible to modify cameras by removing or replacing the filter. It's sometimes done for [astrophotography](http://www.skyandtelescope.com/astronomy-resources/astrophotography-tips/shooting-with-modified-dslr-cameras/) or UV photography, for instance.

It has nothing to do with RAW vs JPEG or other image formats. The spectrum the camera can record depends only on the filters, the glass in the lens, and the sensor itself - some sensor technologies are more sensitive to IR or UV than others.

Answer (score 0):

.RAW is a file format and has nothing to do with the range of electromagnetic spectrum as such. The "Thing" responsible for processing a particular part of the electromagnetic spectrum is your camera's sensor and corresponding circuitry.

To give you a perspective, the .RAW (.CRT in canon) files may be compared to an undeveloped negative of the film days. The raw file is just recorded lights in 128-bit format with no processing done by the camera processor.
Hope that helps.

Comment: 128-bit is a way too much :) You mean 10 till 14-bit (usually).

Comment: Yeah,  can you imagine 2^128 levels?  That's 3.4028e+38 :-)